# WPF - Binding DataGrid items to the ListBox items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, listbox

I have a problem with binding DataGrid items (which might be editable) with ListBox items.
I have added the item to DataGrid (in the cs code), and this item is not shown in the ListBox items.

Here is the xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="_303_slawinskam_5B.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_303_slawinskam_5B"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Movies manager" Height="600" Width="800" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="600" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="#007c04" Offset="0.0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#b2ffb4" Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>

    <Menu Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="792">
        <MenuItem Header="Menu" Width="55" Height="25">
            <MenuItem Header="Help" Click="Help_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Add movies" Click="Add_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="Exit_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <TabControl Margin="10,10,0,10" Background="Transparent" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <TabItem Header="View" Margin="716,39,-735,-47">
            <ListBox Margin="0,0,67,0" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dataGridMovies}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="Title: {Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Director: {Binding Director}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Score: {Binding Score}"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Type: {Binding Type}"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Edit" Margin="679,72,-703,-81">
            <DataGrid Margin="0,6,68,0" Background="Transparent" x:Name="dataGridMovies">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Director" Binding="{Binding Director}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Binding="{Binding Score}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

And here is the cs code:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace _303_slawinskam_5B
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            }

            private void Help_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You won't find any help here");
            }

            private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
            }

            public class Movies
            {
                public string Title { get; set; }
                public string Director { get; set; }
                public string Score { get; set; }
                public string Type { get; set; }
            }

            private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                List<Movies> ml = new List<Movies>();

                dataGridMovies.DataContext = ml;

                Movies check = new Movies() { Title = "title", Director = "director", Score = "score", Type = "type" };
                dataGridMovies.Items.Add(check);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please advise me what do I have to change so that the items added to DataGrid are added to the ListBox as well.
Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144184/discussion-on-question-by-displayed-name-wpf-binding-datagrid-items-to-the-lis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing 2 small correction in your code it will work as you expected:

1) You have to add `Path` as `ItemsSource` of `DataGrid` while binding `ItemsSource` of `ListView` as following.

```
<TabItem Header="View" Margin="716,39,-735,-47">
    <ListBox Margin="0,0,67,0" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=dataGridMovies,Path=ItemsSource}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Title: {Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Director: {Binding Director}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Score: {Binding Score}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="Type: {Binding Type}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</TabItem>
```

**Method 1** --- 2) You should not add Items to `DataGrid` using `Add` method instead assign `ItemsSource` of `DataGrid` to list of `Movies`. Hence,  Change your `Window_Loaded` handler to

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Movies> ml = new List<Movies>();

    dataGridMovies.DataContext = ml;

    Movies check = new Movies() { Title = "title", Director = "director", Score = "score", Type = "type" };
    Movies check1 = new Movies() { Title = "title1", Director = "director1", Score = "score1", Type = "type1" };
    var movies = new List<Movies> {check1, check};
    dataGridMovies.ItemsSource = movies;
}
```

**Method 2** --- 2) Create an `ObservableCollection` of `Movies` and assign that collection to `ItemsSource` of `DataGrid`and update the collection when ever required. In this way you can update dynamically.

```
private ObservableCollection<Movies> MoviesCol { get; set; }

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Movies> ml = new List<Movies>();

    dataGridMovies.DataContext = ml;

    Movies check = new Movies() { Title = "title", Director = "director", Score = "score", Type = "type" };
    Movies check1 = new Movies() { Title = "title1", Director = "director1", Score = "score1", Type = "type1" };
    Movies check2 = new Movies() { Title = "title2", Director = "director2", Score = "score2", Type = "type2" };
    MoviesCol.Add(check1);
    MoviesCol.Add(check);
    dataGridMovies.ItemsSource = MoviesCol;
    MoviesCol.Add(check2);
}
```

and initialize this `MovieCol` property from the `constructor`.

```
MoviesCol = new ObservableCollection<Movies>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But I have one issue. I would want to later add more movies to the DataGrid/ListBox and it doesn't work. It seems like var movies is set as ItemsSource for DataGrid (which is ok) but if I later add more movies to var movie, this change is not reflected. Could you advice some changes ?

Comment: If the answer is correct. Please mark it as correct and mark up. It helps others.

Comment: Thanks, definitely I will mark it. But it is not 100% what I wanted. That is why I have asked you the question above. I would want to have var movies as a global variable and every time after adding movies to var movies the ItemsSource is also updated.

Comment: Check the updated answer. It will help.And in case if it is not helping do let me know.

Comment: @displayed_name, Deepak mentioned something about initializing the collection in the constructor. You can do either that, or you can use a auto-property initializer like `public ObservableCollection<Movies> MoviesCol { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Movies>();`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)

Comment: Yes, Deepak mentioned about it, but I noticed it with a delay. Sorry.

Comment: Also I would want to ask if you know some solution how can I make column Score as a ComboBoxColumn with given values?

Comment: You need to Use `DataGridComboBoxColumn` instead of `DataGridTextColumn` and bind the `ItemsSource` similarly.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I would like to ask you one more thing: I have a question regarding the ObservableCollection. I have "ObservableCollection<Movies> MoviesCol", and I want to delete one item with the specified index. I am doing: "MoviesCol.RemoveAt(j)" but it is not working. Could you please advise me how can I solve this problem ?